# SSH Config Not Working As Expected

Tags: linux, ssh, hosts

I normally connect to a seedbox like so:

```
ssh -D 20000 <user>@<host>
```

It then prompts me for a password:

```
<user>@<host>'s password:
```

Pretty standard stuff. So I set my ~/.ssh/config to look like this

```
Host <name>
HostName <host>
User <user>
Port 20000
```

Yet when doing `ssh <name>` I get

```
ssh: connect to host <host> port 20000: Connection refused
```

Why?

---

Additionally, I tried creating a `.ssh` folder on that server, and setting `authorized_keys` to my `id_rsa.pub` and that also doesn't work for suppressing the asking of the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-D` you use in the command doesn't indicate which port the server is listening for SSH connections (which is what the `Port` line in your SSH config is):

```
-D [bind_address:]port
   Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port forwarding.
```

So you can remove the "Port" line since your server likely uses the standard port (but you may have to continue using the -D for other purposes)

`authorized_keys` is not taken in account unless it is accessible only by the user (in other words its access flags should be `-rw-------`). And likewise the ssh directory should be `drwx------` I think.